# insert in mysql table from .txt file

Tags: php, mysql

i have a situation where i have to insert in mysql table from a .txt file. and data is in format of below. both the data from left and right show seperatly insert into 2 columns. and the 3rd colum show be id

```
koijjh12 : 12
lkoiujjf : 12
uoytresf : 15
kjhgfd56 : 50
```

can we use php script to import that .txt file to the mysql database.

Comment: yes - do regex and construct the insert statements. Fire those vie the command tool `mysql` into the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You certainly can do it via a PHP script, but the best way is to use the [Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) `load data infile` syntax like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

In you case, it looks like the fields are terminated by `:` so you can change it easily enough like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' : '  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

You can run this command from any mysql query function by inserting it as the query. This will be *much* faster than anything you can do in PHP manually (as in reading the text into PHP, then inserting it into the database).

Edit: Be aware that if you use this in a string, you will need to escape the `\` in the newline character with another `\` like this: `LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';`

Comment: Is it possible to receive the data from another host in the same network by using this method?

Answer (score 6):

Something like that:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("a.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $row = explode(":", $line);
    $query = "INSERT INTO tablename SET val1 = '" . trim($row[0]) . "', val2 = '" . trim($row[1]) . "'";
    mysql_query($query);
}

?>
```