# How to insert values in a field of a table in MySQL, from .txt file

Tags: mysql

how can i insert values in a field of a table in MySQL, from a .txt file line for line ?

My .txt is like:

name1
name2
name3
name4

(line per line)

i read a lot on Stackoverflow, i found this: [insert in mysql table from .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089064/insert-in-mysql-table-from-txt-file)

but my situation is little different, i'm triyng to modify the linked post's query, but unsuccesful :-( thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'testfile.txt'
INTO TABLE testtable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(name);
```

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE "/root/id_vecchi.txt" INTO TABLE htaccess(id_vecchio) LINES TERMINATED BY "\r";`
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax :-(

Comment: in this case "htaccess" is the table and "id_vecchio" is the field where insert values line per line

Comment: hi AnandPhadke, but i have a .txt not a .csv :-(

Comment: change it to .txt its just a file name

Comment: You need to have your text file in a format that `LOAD DATA` can understand. It's quite configurable, but isn't psychic.

Comment: @AnandPhadke "name" is the name of field true ? table is "htaccess" and field is "id_vecchio" `mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE "/root/id_vecchi.txt" INTO TABLE htaccess FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINED TERMINATED BY '\n' (id_vecchio);` ERROR 1064 you have an error in your mysql syntax etc... :-(

Comment: give filename in single quote

Comment: @AnandPhadke , ok i did it. now i have `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'wrs'@'%' (using password: YES)` very very strange, obviously the .txt have 777 permission :-( thanks for the support AnandPhadke

Comment: really strange thing.Looks like some setting at your local machine causing problems.Also this file is on the same machine where mysql server is there rite?

Comment: yea this is the same machine :( i'll try to google, for now thanks AnandPhadke, really really thanks for your precious time !